# Is there a fixed format for json for using it in collapsible tree layout?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am using [d3.js](http://d3js.org) for visualizing the data in collapsible tree layout.Its working fine with flare.json data but it seems to have problems with other json files to work.My json file is valid.

The error I am getting is as follows Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of undefined And my json is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Sanjna/LL27P/6/)

```
{
"name":"dummy",
"children":
[

{

    "date": "20040309",
    "name": "US", 
    "id": "27",
    "kind": "S1",
    "application_type": "not found",
    "children": [
        {"length": 27,
            "type": "US",
            "id": "28",
            "kind": "S",
            "name": "Mewdows",
            "date": "19730700",
            "main_classification": "D 2907"
        },
        {"length": 27,
            "type": "US",
            "id": "29",
            "kind": "S",
            "name": "Askew",
            "date": "19731100",
            "main_classification": "D 2907"
        },
        {"length": 27,
            "type": "US",
            "id": "30",
            "kind": "S",
            "name": "Adams",
            "date": "20020500",
            "main_classification": "D 2969"
        },
        {"length": 27,
            "type": "US",
            "id": "31",
            "kind": "S",
            "name": "Adams et al.",
            "date": "20020500",
            "main_classification": "D 2969"
        },
        {"length": 27,
            "type": "US",
            "id": "32",
            "kind": "S",
            "name": "Adams",
            "date": "20020800",
            "main_classification": "D 2969"
        },
        {"length": 27,
            "type": "US",
            "id": "33",
            "kind": "S",
            "name": "Adams",
            "date": "20030700",
            "main_classification": "D 2969"
        },
        {"length": 27,
            "type": "US",
            "id": "34",
            "kind": "S",
            "name": "Robbins",
            "date": "20031000",
            "main_classification": "D 2969"
        }
    ],
    "classification_national": "D 2969",
    "length": 7
},
{

    "date": "20040309",
    "name": "US",
    "id": "30997425",
    "kind": "S1",
    "application_type": "not found",
    "children": [
        {"length": 7,
            "type": "US",
            "id": "35",
            "kind": "A",
            "name": "Alba et al.",
            "date": "19851000",
            "main_classification": "323308"
        },
        {"length": 7,
            "type": "US",
            "id": "36",
            "kind": "A",
            "name": "Dobberstein",
            "date": "19851000",
            "main_classification": "323308"
        }
    ],
    "classification_national": "D13110",
    "length": 2
},

{

    "date": "20040309",
    "name": "US",
    "id": "56992283",
    "kind": "B2",
    "application_type": "not found",
    "children": [
        { "length": 114,
            "type": "US",
            "id": "151",
            "kind": "A",
            "name": "Demetre",
            "date": "19770300",
            "main_classification": "271183"
        },
        {"length": 114,
            "type": "US",
            "id": "152",
            "kind": "A",
            "name": "Carstedt",
            "date": "19771100",
            "main_classification": "271183"
        },
        {"length": 114,
            "type": "US",
            "id": "153",
            "kind": "B1",
            "name": "Teumer et al.",
            "date": "20010100",
            "main_classification": "271194"
        },
        {"length": 114,
            "type": "DE",
            "id": "154",
            "kind": "not found",
            "name": "not found",
            "date": "19751200",
            "main_classification": "not found"
        },
        {"length": 114,
            "type": "DE",
            "id": "155",
            "kind": "not found",
            "name": "not found",
            "date": "19770100",
            "main_classification": "not found"
        },
        {"length": 114,
            "type": "DE",
            "id": "156",
            "kind": "not found",
            "name": "not found",
            "date": "19800300",
            "main_classification": "not found"
        }
    ],
    "classification_national": "271276",
    "length": 6
}
]
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide some source code?

Comment: In order for anyone to help you'll have to show your JSON and list any errors. Also, despite just validating your JSON have you verified you have it in the format that d3 expects it for the collapsible tree?

Comment: The error I am getting is as follows Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of undefined And my json is here http://jsfiddle.net/Sanjna/LL27P/6/

Comment: Your JSON file worked for me, see http://jsfiddle.net/brantolsen/aQMr9/1/.

Comment: Yeah Thanks a lot Brant for the help.Its working perfectly.The zooming  is perfect.
Since I was working on collapsible tree.Any help regarding to that is greatly appreciated.
Thanks again

Comment: Is there still an issue or can this question be closed?

Comment: Yeah there is an issue regarding the working of collapsible tree.
As the tree is not collapsing on clicking.
Thankx again.And apologies for d late reply.